# RTL8821CE(wifi) driver installation issue: KBUILD_MODNAME

Tags: linux, makefile, cross-compiling

I downloaded the following driver for my new HP 17z laptop running Linux Mint 19: https://github.com/endlessm/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/rtl8821ce

Upon modifying the makefile by instruction I ran the "make" command and get the following error:

z

```
ermacroyd@DALEK:~/Downloads/rtl8821ce$ make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/build M=/home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_security.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_debug.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_io.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_mlme.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_mi.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_vht.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_rf.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_recv.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_ap.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_p2p.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_tdls.o
  CC [M]  /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_br_ext.o
In file included from ./include/linux/printk.h:350:0,
                 from ./include/linux/kernel.h:14,
                 from ./include/linux/skbuff.h:17,
                 from ./include/linux/if_arp.h:26,
                 from /home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_br_ext.c:23:
./include/net/inet_connection_sock.h: In function ‘inet_csk_clear_xmit_timer’:
./include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:77:14: error: ‘KBUILD_MODNAME’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘KBUILD_BASENAME’?
   .modname = KBUILD_MODNAME,   \
              ^
./include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:99:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA_KEY’
  DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA_KEY(name, fmt, .key.dd_key_false, \
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:125:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA’
  DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA(descriptor, fmt);  \
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/printk.h:354:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘dynamic_pr_debug’
  dynamic_pr_debug(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/net/inet_connection_sock.h:216:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘pr_debug’
   pr_debug("%s", inet_csk_timer_bug_msg);
   ^~~~~~~~
./include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:77:14: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
   .modname = KBUILD_MODNAME,   \
              ^
./include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:99:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA_KEY’
  DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA_KEY(name, fmt, .key.dd_key_false, \
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:125:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA’
  DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA(descriptor, fmt);  \
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/printk.h:354:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘dynamic_pr_debug’
  dynamic_pr_debug(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/net/inet_connection_sock.h:216:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘pr_debug’
   pr_debug("%s", inet_csk_timer_bug_msg);
   ^~~~~~~~
./include/net/inet_connection_sock.h: In function ‘inet_csk_reset_xmit_timer’:
./include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:77:14: error: ‘KBUILD_MODNAME’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘KBUILD_BASENAME’?
   .modname = KBUILD_MODNAME,   \
              ^
./include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:99:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA_KEY’
  DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA_KEY(name, fmt, .key.dd_key_false, \
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:125:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA’
  DEFINE_DYNAMIC_DEBUG_METADATA(descriptor, fmt);  \
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/printk.h:354:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘dynamic_pr_debug’
  dynamic_pr_debug(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/net/inet_connection_sock.h:232:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘pr_debug’
   pr_debug("reset_xmit_timer: sk=%p %d when=0x%lx, caller=%p\n",
   ^~~~~~~~
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_br_ext.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce/core/rtw_br_ext.o] Error 1
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/zermacroyd/Downloads/rtl8821ce] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic'
Makefile:1897: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

The problem file is rtw_br_ext.c which uses headers from the Linux kernel. So there are NO KBUILD flags in the makefile. What is the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

do not make changes to the make file.
without making changes run the file and it will run Ok. 
On that Github url, there is no instruction for changing the make file.